# Shell script for fresh EE install

Tags: permissions, install

Has anyone written a shell script to set all the default file/folder permissions on a new EE install?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create .sh file and use below command to set permissions to folders.

```
chmod -Rvf 0777 folder_path/folder_name/
```

Comment: Thanks! I'll put it together.

Answer (score 0):

You can modify next scripts for your needs:

[source](https://gist.github.com/MaxLazar/928848211f56bd1f244511e2d0574b6e)

```
#!/bin/bash

# Find location of this script.
# This ensures that only files in the directory in
# which this script exists (recursively) are modified.
DIR="$( cd "$( dirname "${BASH_SOURCE[0]}" )" && pwd )"

# Set what the name of your expressionengine folders are.
SYSTEM="system"
IMAGES_DIR="public_html/images"
UPLOADS_DIR="public_html/files"

# Optionally ensure correct ownership on per environment basis.
#if [ "$DIR" = "/path/to/project/" ]; then
#   chown -R http.http "$DIR"
#fi

# Expressionengine specific permissions.
find "$DIR" -type d -print0 | xargs -0 chmod 0755
find "$DIR" -type f -print0 | xargs -0 chmod 0644
find "$DIR/$IMAGES_DIR/" -type d -print0 | xargs -0 chmod -R go+w
find "$DIR/$UPLOADS_DIR/" -type d -print0 | xargs -0 chmod -R go+w
chmod -R go+w "$DIR/$SYSTEM/user/templates"
chmod -R go+w "$DIR/$SYSTEM/user/cache"
chmod 0666 "$DIR/$SYSTEM/user/config/config.php"

# Permissions specific to the sitemap generator
# from http://www.xml-sitemaps.com/.
#chmod -R 0777 "$DIR/public_html/generator/data"
#chmod 0666 "$DIR/public_html/sitemap.xml"
#chmod 0666 "$DIR/public_html/ror.xml"
#chmod 0600 "$DIR/public_html/index.php"


# If laxative is being used, preserve executability
#if [ -e "$DIR/.db/lax" ]; then
#    chmod 0700 "$DIR/.db/lax"
#fi

# Make sure other shell scripts are executable too.
find "$DIR" -type f -name "*.sh" -print0 | xargs -0 chmod 700
```